# Removal of large list of strings from a text

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Suppose that

```
txt='Daniel Johnson and Ana Hickman are friends. They know each other for a long time. Daniel Johnson is a professor and Ana Hickman is writer.'
```

is a large piece of text and I want to remove a big list of strings such as

```
removalLists=['Daniel Johnson','Ana Hickman']
```

from them. I mean I want to replace all the elements in the list by

```
' '
```

I know that I can do it easily using a loop for such as

```
for string in removalLists:
    txt=re.sub(string,' ',txt)
```

I wonder if I can do it faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to generate a single regex pattern which is an alternation of the replacement terms.  So, I am suggesting to use the following regex pattern, for your example:

```
\bDaniel Johnson\b|\bAna Hickman\b
```

To generate this, we can first wrap each term with word boundaries (`\b`).  Then, collapse the list to a single string using `|` as the separator.  Finally, we can use `re.sub` to replace all occurrences of any term with a single space.

```
txt = 'Daniel Johnson and Ana Hickman are friends. They know each other for a long time. Daniel Johnson is a professor and Ana Hickman is writer.'
removalLists = ['Daniel Johnson','Ana Hickman']

regex = '|'.join([r'\b' + s + r'\b' for s in removalLists])
output = re.sub(regex, " ", txt)

print(output)

  and   are friends. They know each other for a long time.   is a professor and   is writer.
```

Comment: The word boundaries make this take more time than OP's code for [me](https://gist.github.com/CertainPerformance/18159f3100ae8dc1352f53793d94fa8c) if I did the performance check right. If the items should be surrounded by word boundaries, best to put the `\b`s *outside* a non-capturing group that alternates between each item, `regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(removalLists) + r')\b'`. (the regex gets more performant than the `for string in removalLists` the more items are in the list though)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I get it.  Thanks for the comment.  I won't poach your idea, but someone who wants a faster solution may do so.