# Python: Faster way to filter a list using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension, binary-search

Consider the following problem: I want to keep elements of list1 that belongs to list2. So I can do something like this:

```
filtered_list = [w for w in list1 if w in list2]
```

I need to repeat this same procedure for different examples of list1 (about 20000 different examples) and a "constant" (frozen) list2.

**How can I speed up the process?**

I also know the following properties:

1) list1 has repeated elements and it is not sorted and it has about 10000 (ten thousand) items.

2) list2 is a giant sorted list (about 200000 - two hundred thousand) entries in Python) and each element is unique.

The first thing that comes to me is that maybe I can use a kind of binary search. However, is there a way to do this in Python?

Furthermore, I do not mind if filtered_list has the same order of items of list1. So, maybe I can check only a unrepeated version of list1 and after removing the elements in list1 that do not belong to list 2, I can return the repeated items.

Is there a fast way to do this in Python 3?

Comment: are the elements strings or byte sequences? This seems perfect for [Aho-Corasick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) in this case. You can give a try to [pyahocorasick](https://pypi.org/project/pyahocorasick/). Add some example code to let me give an answer, eventually.

Comment: @Sigismondo Doubtful... Aho-Corasick is awesome at finding substrings (or subsequences, more generally), can't do anything about list intersections AFAIK.

Comment: thinking... actually yes, I though that list1 was some sort of text. If the list1 elements are independent you are absolutely right!

Comment: @Sigismondo both are lists of strings. I haven't got if this could be another solution or not.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: No - Aho-Corasick is all about looking for _substrings_ in a big string. You are looking for exact matches shared between lists.

Comment: @Amadan can it be used to remove a large numbers of strings from a big string? A kind of regex replace? Something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698404/removal-of-large-list-of-strings-from-a-text

Comment: It is similar to regex in that it just _looks for substrings_. Replacing is something that each implementing language adds, and got connected to regex in people's minds; but neither regex nor aho-corasick inherently do it, they just tell you where stuff is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `list2` to a `set`:

```
# do once
set2 = set(list2)

# then every time
filtered_list = [w for w in list1 if w in set2]
```

`x in list2` is sequential; `x in set2` uses the same mechanism as dictionaries, resulting in a very quick lookup.

If `list1` didn't have duplicates, converting both to sets and taking set intersection would be the way to go:

```
filtered_set = set1 & set2
```

but with duplicates you're stuck with iterating over `list1` as above.

(As you said, you could even see elements that you should delete, using `set1 - set2`, but then you'd still be stuck in a loop in order to delete - there shouldn't be any difference in performance between filtering keepers vs filtering trash, you still have to iterate over `list1`, so that's no win over the method above.)

EDIT in response to comment: Converting `list1` to a `Counter` <strike>would</strike> might (EDIT: or not; testing needed!) speed it up *if you can use it normally like that* (i.e. you never have a list, you always just deal with a `Counter`). But if you have to preprocess `list1` into `counter1` each time you do the above operation, again it's no win - creating a `Counter` will again involve a loop.

Comment: I would improve the process if set2 is a frozen set or it does not matter? Could I maybe convert every list1 to a dictionary where for each word there is the number of times that the word arises? However, I would spend extra time with this process.Does it make any sense?

Comment: See above regarding "a dictionary where for each word there is the number of times that the word arises" (effectively `collections.Counter`). And see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36555214/set-vs-frozenset-performance) regarding `frozenset`.